# Can only call -[PFObject init] on subclasses conforming to PFSubclassing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am getting the following error

> Can only call -[PFObject init] on subclasses conforming to
>   PFSubclassing

This is my code

```
var likeObject = PFObject()
let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username!
likeObject.addUniqueObject(user!, forKey: "likers")
```

I am confused as to why I am getting this error. The project runs as it should but when I click the button associated with this function, it crashes and I get that error message. I looked and found something similar to this in Obj-c but I am looking for the answer in Swift, can anybody help me out? In my head, this should work just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of a generic `PFObject` - you can't do that. All instances need to have a specified class name.

If you're using a subclass then it specifies the class name so you can instantiate it directly.

If you're using `PFObject` then you need to use `initWithClassName:` to specify the class name.